# Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload] (Term Menu Order)

Tags: errors, warnings

I'm developing a site and found this error on top of every page of the site:

```
Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access videopress.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access polldaddyshortcode.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access vaultpress.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access k35r0vc.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42

Warning: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Unable to access wp_user_search.class.php in /home/stopecom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/term-menu-order/term-menu-order.php on line 42
```

It only happens in live server though. When I tried it on localhost, there is no problem there.

I realize it's a problem caused by a plugin, [Term Menu Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-menu-order/). I've been trying to look for more information regarding `spl_autoload`, I also have tried to consult the author via support forum. However I hardly can deduct anything from my search results, and because the author's last reply was almost a year ago, I'm starting to get pessimistic.

Why is it happening only in live servers, and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Check the permissions on those files and their directories. It looks like the system can't find/read those class files. I don't think this is a WordPress specific question.

Comment: This has been [reported on github issue tracker](https://github.com/billerickson/Term-Menu-Order/issues/2) for the plugin, but it seems person currently maintaining it is not the original developer. And yes - it's probably not WordPress-specific...

Comment: Ah yes, I was worried whether this is appropriate to post on Wordpress SE or not... regarding the file permission, all permissions for the files under the plugin folder is now set to 755, but the warning remains. Does the problem lie on another part?

Answer (score 2):

I would say if the plugin author hasn't responded to support in a year that you should dump the plugin causing the issue and find something else. You're bound to run into more problems in the future. And, yes, s_ha_dum is right that it probably has something to do with the permissions on those files on your server.

Comment: Regarding the file permission, all permissions for the files under the plugin folder is now set to 755, but the warning remains. Does the problem lie on another part? Or is it a problem caused by the hosting?